IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3, Please Resolve
I'm new to computer vision and designing a program for car damage detection system on Google Colab. I had trained two models for detecting damage and car parts as instance segmentation done using Detectron2, which I'm trying to load in the system but it keeps failing due to "too many indices for tensor of dimesion 3" error despite the input shape being correct. Please help me out.
Extra info: The input consists of 8 images of standard angles of a damaged car and result would be the car parts which are detected as damaged.
Here is the code -
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.modeling import build_model

def load_model(model_config_path, model_weights_path):
    # Load the model configuration from the config.yaml file
    cfg = get_cfg()
    cfg.merge_from_file(model_config_path)
    
    # Build the model architecture
    model = build_model(cfg)
    
    # Load the weights
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_weights_path))
    
    # Set the model to evaluation mode
    model.eval()
    
    return model



def load_and_preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((640, 640)),  # Adjust size according to model requirements
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])
    img = transform(image)
    img = img.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a batch dimension
    print("Preprocessed image shape:", img.shape)
    return {"image": img, "image_path": image_path}


image_folder = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/images/"
image_paths = [os.path.join(image_folder, f"{angle}.jpg") for angle in range(1, 9)]
batched_inputs = [load_and_preprocess_image(image_path) for image_path in image_paths]

print("Number of batched inputs:", len(batched_inputs))

def detect_parts(model, image):
    # Ensure the input tensor has the correct shape
    if len(image.shape) == 3:
        image = image.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a batch dimension if it's missing
    print("Input image shape:", image.shape)  # Print the shape of the input tensor
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(image)  # No need to permute dimensions here
    return output

def determine_position(image_name):
    positions = {
        "front": ["Front", "Front Left", "Front Right"],
        "rear": ["Rear", "Rear Left", "Rear Right"],
        "left": ["Left", "Front Left", "Rear Left"],
        "right": ["Right", "Front Right", "Rear Right"]
    }
    for position, keywords in positions.items():
        if any(keyword.lower() in image_name.lower() for keyword in keywords):
            return position
    return "Unknown"

# Load the models
carparts_model = load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/parts/config.yaml", "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/parts/carparts.pth")
damagedetect_model = load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/damage/config.yaml", "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/damage/damagedetect.pth")

# Define the parts of the car
car_parts = [
    "back_bumper", "back_glass", "back_left_door", "back_left_light", 
    "back_right_door", "back_right_light", "car", "front_bumper", 
    "front_glass", "front_left_door", "front_left_light", "front_right_door", 
    "front_right_light", "hood", "left_mirror", "right_mirror", "tailgate", "trunk", "wheel"
]


for angle in range(1, 9):
    image_path = f"{image_folder}{angle}.jpg"
    position = determine_position(image_path)
    
    print(f"Checking angle {angle}, image path: {image_path}")
    print(f"Length of batched_inputs: {len(batched_inputs)}")
    
    # Check if batched_inputs has enough elements
    if len(batched_inputs) >= angle:
        print(f"Accessing batched_inputs at index {angle-1}")
        # Detect parts of the car
        parts_output = detect_parts(carparts_model, batched_inputs[angle-1]["image"])
        parts_prediction = torch.argmax(parts_output, dim=1)
        detected_parts = [car_parts[idx] for idx in parts_prediction]
        
        # Detect damaged parts
        damaged_output = detect_parts(damagedetect_model, batched_inputs[angle-1]["image"])
        damaged_prediction = torch.argmax(damaged_output, dim=1)
        damaged_parts = [car_parts[idx] for idx in damaged_prediction]

        print(f"Image: {angle}.jpg")
        print(f"Position: {position}")
        print("Detected Parts:", detected_parts)
        print("Damaged Parts:", damaged_parts)
        print("----------------------------------")
    else:
        print(f"Not enough elements in batched_inputs for angle {angle}")

Here's what error I get -
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
WARNING:fvcore.common.config:Loading config /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/parts/config.yaml with yaml.unsafe_load. Your machine may be at risk if the file contains malicious content.
Preprocessed image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
Number of batched inputs: 8
WARNING:fvcore.common.config:Loading config /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/damage/config.yaml with yaml.unsafe_load. Your machine may be at risk if the file contains malicious content.
Checking angle 1, image path: /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/car/images/1.jpg
Length of batched_inputs: 8
Accessing batched_inputs at index 0
Input image shape: torch.Size([1, 3, 800, 800])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-e7be7dbf072e> in <cell line: 80>()
     89         print(f"Accessing batched_inputs at index {angle-1}")
     90         # Detect parts of the car
---> 91         parts_output = detect_parts(carparts_model, batched_inputs[angle-1]["image"])
     92         parts_prediction = torch.argmax(parts_output, dim=1)
     93         detected_parts = [car_parts[idx] for idx in parts_prediction]

6 frames
<ipython-input-27-e7be7dbf072e> in detect_parts(model, image)
     50     print("Input image shape:", image.shape)  # Print the shape of the input tensor
     51     with torch.no_grad():
---> 52         output = model(image)  # No need to permute dimensions here
     53     return output
     54 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510         else:
-> 1511             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1512 
   1513     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1518                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1521 
   1522         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py in forward(self, batched_inputs)
    148         """
    149         if not self.training:
--> 150             return self.inference(batched_inputs)
    151 
    152         images = self.preprocess_image(batched_inputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py in inference(self, batched_inputs, detected_instances, do_postprocess)
    201         assert not self.training
    202 
--> 203         images = self.preprocess_image(batched_inputs)
    204         features = self.backbone(images.tensor)
    205 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py in preprocess_image(self, batched_inputs)
    225         Normalize, pad and batch the input images.
    226         """
--> 227         images = [self._move_to_current_device(x["image"]) for x in batched_inputs]
    228         images = [(x - self.pixel_mean) / self.pixel_std for x in images]
    229         images = ImageList.from_tensors(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    225         Normalize, pad and batch the input images.
    226         """
--> 227         images = [self._move_to_current_device(x["image"]) for x in batched_inputs]
    228         images = [(x - self.pixel_mean) / self.pixel_std for x in images]
    229         images = ImageList.from_tensors(

IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3


output = model([image])  # No need to permute dimensions here?

This was chatGPT's suggestion earlier it permuting the shape since it wasn't aware of the dimensions.
